# Restful Web service search

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, xslt

I am trying to do a simple search of a restful xml web service but getting no output.

Examples: 
http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=healthTopics&term=asthma

More info here: http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/webservices.html

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DoSearch() {


            var searchVal = $('#searchString').val();
            alert('called ' + searchVal);
            var url = "http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=healthTopics&term="+searchVal;
            $.get(url, function( data ) {
                $( "#resultsDiv" ).html( data );
                alert( "Load was performed." );
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <input id ="searchString" type="text" /><input type="button" value="Search" onclick="DoSearch();" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="resultsDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should probably mention I am very new to Javascript! :)

Comment: [Reference](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/writing-a-javascript-rest-client)